# PowerShell Script Template

Tags: powershell

I'm working on creating a script template to jump start the creation of new powershell scripts.

A quick list of some of the things I'm considering:

- params block
- usage function
- main function
- support for -verbose, -debug etc

Does anyone have something like this already, that they could share?